# XSLT: Insert nodes at root of svg file

Tags: xml, xslt

My goal is to add the two nodes `<style>` and `<whatever>` to my SVG file using the XSLT below, but I'm facing two problems. First, when adding `<style>`, it's including three `xmlns` attributes I don't want:

```
<style xmlns=""
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">.val{--valence: #4599a3}</style>
```

Then, it's not adding my second node `<whatever>`.

How can I fix it ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version='1.0'>

    <!-- this template is applied by default to all nodes and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <!-- just copy all my attributes and child nodes, except if there's a better template for some of them -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="svg:title">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <style>.val{--valence: #4599a3}</style>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="svg:title">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <whatever>foo</whatever>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="svg:defs/svg:circle">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">fill: var(--valence, #47565b)</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add elements in the SVG namespace then you need to use it, so if the whole stylesheet is supposed to create SVG elements and you have it already declared on the root element as you have with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version='1.0'>
```

you can create an SVG `style` element using `svg:style`:

```
   <xsl:template match="svg:title">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <svg:style>.val{--valence: #4599a3}</svg:style>
   </xsl:template>
```

As an alternative, you can put a default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` on the root element of the stylesheet e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version='1.0'>

  ..
   <xsl:template match="svg:title">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <style>.val{--valence: #4599a3}</style>
   </xsl:template>
```

`xsl:element` is not needed.

As for the other namespace declarations you declare on the root element for XPath expressions or XSLT match patterns but you don't want to be used for result elements, you can use the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute on `xsl:stylesheet`/`xsl:transform` e.g. `exclude-result-prefixes="xsi svg"`

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
      xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
      xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
      xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      exclude-result-prefixes="xsi svg"
      version='1.0'>

    <!-- this template is applied by default to all nodes and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <!-- just copy all my attributes and child nodes, except if there's a better template for some of them -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="svg:title">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <style>.val{--valence: #4599a3}</style>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQeY

Answer (score 1):

1. Namespaces are inherited. To get rid of them, you need to set another namespace or an empty namespace (creating the `xmlns=""` which means no namespace/empty namespace).  To remove the

   ```
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   ```

   One way you can solve this is by explicitly defining the element with an `xsl:element`:

   ```
   <xsl:element name="whatever" namespace="">foo</xsl:element>
   ```

   Now you only have the `xmlns=""` left on the element. To also remove this, set the namespace to the default namespace - here probably `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`

   ```
   <xsl:element name="whatever" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">foo</xsl:element>
   ```

   Now the element appears as `<whatever>foo</whatever>`, but remember that it actually has the inherited default namespace.
2. > Then, it's not adding my second node `<whatever>`.

   This happens because you have two templates with the same matching rule `match="svg:title"`. Make the matching rules unique and it will work.

Comment: To avoid anyone being misled, this solution works, but it's not the only way of doing it; the suggestion that the problem can only be solved using `xsl:element` is not quite right.